# Why does window.setTimeout() become to a loop call after using window.setInterval()

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

**I want to count from 5 to 1 so I write code in Chrome console like this :**

```
var a = 5;
window.setInterval (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
window.clearInterval();
```

**The console shows this result:**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

**And then I run another piece of code after it:**

```
var a = 5;
window.setTimeout (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
```

**And I find the console shows this result:**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

**Why `setTimeout()` becomes a loop ? It was supposed to print a single *5* !!!**

> Here is the console : 
>   [image]

Comment: *"It's a right answer."* - No, the *output* is right, but the interval is not cleared and it continues to run every second forever, just not logging anything once `a` reaches 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.clearInterval()` doesn’t do anything by itself, and redeclaring a variable with `var` will just assign to the original variable, so when you set `var a = 5;` the original `setInterval` callback continues to run.

Pass `clearInterval` the return value of `setInterval` instead:

```
var a = 5;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
```

```
// after output has been produced
clearInterval(timer);
```

If you want `clearInterval` to happen automatically once `a` hits `0`, put it inside the callback:

```
var a = 5;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (a > 0)
        console.log(a--);
    else
        clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If I am right, He is asking why setTimeout run as a loop instead of run one time and quit. It behave like set interval

Comment: @Ryan - If you call `clearInterval()` like that then nothing will be logged because it will be cleared before the first one. Though I'm sure you are correct about what is happening with the OP's full code including `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Ah, thanks, I missed that they were part of the same “line”.

Comment: I see it . when  the second time I write `var a = 5`,  `setInterval()` will run again ~~ so it seems like `setTimtout()` runs a loop but in fact it is `setInterval()` which is runing again~

Comment: @Saber - The interval continues running the whole time, it's just that it has no visible output when `a` is <= 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly anticipating that setTimeout has become a loop.

This is what happens. First you run the following code

```
var a = 5;
window.setInterval (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
window.clearInterval();
```

In above code the callback function will be called every second and if value of a is greater than 0 it will decrement it by 1.
Note that `window.clearInterval()` line of code has no effect here so the callback function will keep on running but just stop printing to console because condition will not fall true when value of a is less than 0 or equal to 0

## The callback is still running, just not printing to console

Now you run the following code

```
var a = 5;
window.setTimeout (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
```

This will first set the value of `a` to 5

## This is where the cavet is.

Since you again set the value of a to 5 the `setInterval` callback is still being executed every second. So now the condition will evaluate to `true` and hence it prints to console.

## What prints to console and you think of it as it being printed by `setTimeout` is actually being printed by `setInteval`

If you run the following code you will see what is acutally happeing

```
var a = 5;
var timer = setInterval (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log('From setInterval : ',a--);
    console.log('SetInterval is still running');
}, 1000);

var a = 5;
window.setTimeout (function() {
    if(a > 0)
      console.log(a--);
}, 1000);
```

Hope this clears your doubt conceptually. :-)

Comment: The timeout would also print to the console once.

Comment: I see it . when the second time I write var a = 5,  it seems like setTimtout() runs a loop but in fact it is setInterval() which is still runing

Comment: Exactly @Saber :-). If you want to stop the `setInteval` callback execution do something like this `var timer = setInterval(function(){}, 1000); clearInterval(timer)`